Setting Up CertBot with Azure Kubernetes -- Ingress Issue
I have set up the project on Azure Kubernetes. I have two services: an API and a front end, which are working correctly.
But when I configure certbot, ingress is not routing the request to the certbot pod.
How I set certbot: certbot-deplyment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: certbot
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: certbot
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: certbot
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: certbot
        image: certbot/certbot
        args: [
          "certonly", 
          "--webroot", 
          "--webroot-path=/var/www/certbot", 
          "--email", "abc@example.com", 
          "--agree-tos", 
          "--no-eff-email", 
          "--force-renewal", 
          "--staging",  # <-- This enables staging environment
          "-d staging.example.com"
        ]
        
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 3600"]  # Keep container alive for 1 hour
        volumeMounts:
        - name: certbot-webroot
          mountPath: /var/www/certbot
        - name: certbot-storage
          mountPath: /etc/letsencrypt
        # Disable liveness and readiness probes
        livenessProbe: null
        readinessProbe: null
      volumes:
      - name: certbot-webroot
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: certbot-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: certbot-pvc

certbot-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: certbot
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: certbot  # Make sure this label matches your Certbot pod
  type: ClusterIP


Ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: exampleapp
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules:
    - host: staging.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /.well-known/acme-challenge
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: certbot
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: appbackend
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: appfrontend
                port:
                  number: 80

Here are logs from the nginx load balancer pod:
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 305 "http://staging.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0" 538 0.001 [default-appfrontend-80] [] 10.244.0.218:80 305 0.001 200 c607eb8c784c2c4c494653aa99e28655


Add an annotation to disable SSL redirection for the ACME challenge path. CertBot needs to handle requests over HTTP. https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/http-requests-used-by-certbot/188312

@Arko Thank you. I used the cert-manager with helm and able to resolve it. I have following this: https://medium.com/@anilbidary/domain-name-based-routing-on-aks-azure-kubernetes-service-using-ingress-cert-manager-and-9b4028d762ed

Cool, you can update it as your answer. Will be useful for someone facing similar issue on Stack overflow.

I am posting this as a solution for this question, suggesting the use of cert manager only. Please feel free to add or edit this answer to add any points which I have missed. It can be useful for someone looking for answer for similar issue on SO.
To resolve the issue of Ingress not routing requests to the CertBot pod, I recommend using cert-manager instead of manually configuring CertBot as it simplifies the process of managing TLS certificates with Kubernetes and automates certificate issuance and renewal through Let's Encrypt.
Install cert-manager (I'm using helm)
kubectl label namespace ingress cert-manager.io/disable-validation=true

helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update

helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace ingress \
  --version v1.12.1 \
  --set installCRDs=true



Create a ClusterIssuer for Let's Encrypt
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: arko@stackoverflow.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-account-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx


Update your Ingress resource to use cert-manager
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: exampleapp
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: whatever name you have registered with your DNS provider (such as GoDaddy etc)
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: appfrontend
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: appbackend
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - whatever name you have registered with your DNS provider (such as GoDaddy etc)
    secretName: staging-tls

This will request a TLS certificate and store it in the secret staging-tls.

Detailed steps are mentioned here
